# Simple efficient concatenation of CSV files

Tags: shell-script, csv

Consider a large number of CSV files (`*.csv`) living in some folder. They all have the same exact header.

How can I efficiently concatenate them all into a single CSV file with the same single header?

---

I found a number of solutions that solve similar but more specific problems.

- [Efficient data extraction from multiple files to a single CSV file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217764/efficient-data-extraction-from-multiple-files-to-a-single-csv-file)
- [How to concatenate a variable number of csv, removing their header rows?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178706/how-to-concatenate-a-variable-number-of-csv-removing-their-header-rows)

---

The current `awk` solution doesn't work.

```
$ cat concat_my_csv_files.sh
    #!/usr/bin/env zsh
    awk '
        FNR==1 && NR!=1 { while (/^<header>/) getline; }
        1 {print}
    ' $1/*.csv > $2

$ ./concat_my_csv_files /some/path/to/csv/files/ full_join.csv
```

when I do:

```
grep -F column_A full_join.csv
```

I see several rows having it.

Comment: Then maybe [Concatenate multiple files with same header](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60577) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '
    NR == 1 {print}
    FNR == 1 {next}
    {print}
' *.csv
```

The `NR` variable is the record number of all the input.
The `FNR` variable is the record number of only the current file.

This prints the first line seen by awk (the header of the first file), then will skip the first line of each file, printing all the other lines.

Comment: Note, this can be logically shortened to: `awk 'NR == 1 || FNR > 1' *.csv`

Comment: How are we supposed to help you when you don't show us what your files look like? In the absence of actual information, I'm assuming your "header" is one line at the top of each file.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you want "head -n 1 firstorany.csv; tail -n +2 *.csv".

```
set -- *.csv
head -n 1 "$1"
tail -n +2 "$@"
```

If you have *.csv as arguments in a sh script, omit the first line.

Comment: Thanks. How do I control where the output is written here? (e.g. see `concat_my_csv_files.sh` in the OP update).

Comment: ( head ...; tail ... ) > output.csv